# What is wrong with my palindrome?

Tags: java

Problem:

5. Develop a recursive algorithm to determine if there is a palindrome hidden within a longer word or phrase. A palindrome is a word or phrase that has the same sequence of letters when read from left to right and when read from right to left, ignoring the spaces (e.g., `Some like cake, but I prefer pie` contains the palindrome `I prefer pi`).

Below is my code:

```
public class e125 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        String sLine = "Some like cake, but I prefer pie";
        sLine.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        System.out.println(PlainRet(sLine, i));
    }

    public static String PlainRet(String sLine, int i) {
        int nNum;
        char c = 0;
        String sPlain = "";
        if (i >= sLine.length()) {
            return "No Plaindrome";
        }
        c = sLine.charAt(i);
        nNum = Isgood(sLine, c, i);
        if (nNum != 0) {
            for (; i < nNum; i++) {
                sPlain += sLine.charAt(i);
            }
            return sPlain;
        }
        return PlainRet(sLine, i + 1);
    }

    public static int Isgood(String sLine, char c, int i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sLine.length(); j++) {
            if (Character.toUpperCase(sLine.charAt(j)) == Character.toUpperCase(c)) {
                if (Isplain(sLine, i, j)) {
                    return j;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static boolean Isplain(String sLine, int i, int j) {
        if (Character.toUpperCase(sLine.charAt(j)) != Character.toUpperCase(sLine.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (i == j || j == i + 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return (Isplain(sLine, i + 1, j - 1));
    }
}
```

I keep getting an output of "I"

I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to programming. It's our daily job, as programmers, to find why some code doesn't work the way we think or would like. Add traces in the code (`System.out.println`) or, better, use your debugger to execute the code line by line and inspect the values of the variables at each step, to diagnose the problem.

Comment: `String` is immutable. `.replaceAll()` creates a new `String` with the replacement, so you really want `sLine = sLine.replaceAll(...);`

Comment: a single character phrase is by definition its own palindrome, since it's the same from both directions. Your code needs to explicitly require 2+ characters, since a proper palindrome couldn't be any shorter.

Comment: You might want to post this question at Code Review rather than here.

Comment: @RockOnRockOut Code Review is more for *working* code; if OP's code is returning output that is not expected, it isn't working.

Comment: Answer with an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Like [FatalError](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172428/fatalerror) commented `sLine.replaceAll()` returns a new `String`. You need to reassign sLine or pass the results of the `replaceAll()` into the method.

You'll find a new error to fix after you do that, but it's just an off-by-one!